# MS Graph - URL syntax for sorting Excel filtered rows

Tags: excel, sorting, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to retrieve sorted/filtered rows from Excel using Microsoft Graph API but no matter what URL structure (I tried many) I try, the results are not sorted.

The only way I managed was by sorting the original table (i.e. not using a workbook-session-id) but that is not an option for me. I must not affect the spreadsheet.

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/<groupid>/drive/root:/test.xlsx:/workbook/createSession
BODY => {persistChanges:false}

// retrieved the id

POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/<groupid>/drive/root:/test.xlsx:/workbook/worksheets('test')/tables('test')/sort/apply
HEADER => workbook-session-id: session_Id
BODY => { fields: [{ key: column, ascending: false }], hasHeaders: true}


POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/<groupid>/drive/root:/test.xlsx:/workbook/worksheets('test')/tables('test')/columns('description')/filter/apply
HEADER => workbook-session-id: session_Id
BODY => { criteria: {  filterOn: "Custom",  criterion1: "=" + filter, operator: "Or", criterion2: null }  } 

GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/<groupid>/drive/root:/test.xlsx:/workbook/worksheets('test')/tables('test')/range/visibleView/rows?$select=values
```

The rows are returned filtered but not sorted. Ideally I would prefer to sort after filtering but I could not figure out the URL to use.

Answer (score 0):

Excel API does not support sorting through the URL sort command. It has to be done at the file level. The `persistChanges:false` will ensure that file is not saved. Could you not sort, filter and get the `visibleView` from that series of action? Note that you still need to use the `workbook-session-id` header. It's just that when you set the persist change to false, the changes you make doesn't get saved to the server. However, you can continue to interact for the length of that non-persistent session. When you don't use the session Id, the request is treated as a persist command (though lot slower).